# Basic obstacle detection tutorials using Kinect

Tags: kinect, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

My name is Kartik and being fairly new to kinect and ros, I was wondering if there were any obstacle detection samples using the kinect sensor that I could have a look at? I'm working with robots from clearpath robotics.

I'm trying to use the pointcloud2 data. I plan to follow the steps:

1. Write subscriber node to obtain data from the /camera/depth/points node
2. Process data to be able to detect obstacles based on change in depth values
3. Integrate that with some movement code to able to move/stop robot in the presence of obstacles.

Any help/guidance in this area will be much appreciated!

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29978/basic-obstacle-detection-tutorials-using-kinect/) by [kartikrv](https://answers.ros.org/users/1991/kartikrv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-03-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Basically you are talking about the navigation stack with obstacle avoidance. ROS already has a navigation stack that you can make use of. You may look into http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation and http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Build%20a%20map%20with%20SLAM for using kinect in your navigation and mapping.

Hope it helps

Karthik

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2012-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rasoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/26785/rasoo/) on 2016-09-05**:
Hi, basically I also want to do the same as @kartikrv, but I am using RObotino and Kinect. my robot has no laser sensor. Can you please suggest me how I implement ROS navigation using robotino and kinect?